# Int Pixel Array To Image

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap, bufferedimage

I am trying to take an int array of pixels from a Bitmap on Android and use the int array to make a buffered image. But I'm having some problems. I am able to get the bitmap from android with no problem:

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int)(b.getWidth() * .3125), (int)(b.getHeight() * .44444444444), false);
int[] arr = new int[b.getHeight() * b.getWidth()];
b.getPixels(arr, 0, b.getWidth(), 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
```

I scale the bitmap down and then get the pixels and put them into the int array. Then I send them over a network to the PC where I try to recreate it to a BufferedImage (networking isn't important). Here is the code I use to convert the pixel array to a BufferedImage.

```
int width = 600;
int height = 479;

BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
bi.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, arr, 0, width);
g2d.drawImage(bi, 10, 50, null);
```

The variable "arr" is the byte array of pixels. Converting to a BufferedImage gives no error and shows the following image: [image]

Obviously this isn't the picture I am trying to get. When I print out 5 of the pixels in the array (just for testing) I get the following and this is the format of the pixels:

```
-15528956
-15200766
-13558523
-11718123
-12243954
-13294582
```

Comment: First thing, I would remove the network constraint. Just try to to read your image in an int array, then try to write it in a BufferedImage. This will assert that there is no problem with your network handling.

Comment: Well the reason I can't do that is that the Android device doesnt have the BufferedImage class. But I did do checking to make sure that the pixels matched after transfer and they do. So that I'm not worried about. I also realized that It looks like the first "lines" of pixels that you see are what are coming from the picture. Then you can see it starts to get chopped up. I'm trying to find out why now. I think it may have something to do with how I am getting the pixels from the Bitmap

Comment: Why not store the image as a PNG on Android, and open using ImageIO on Java server side? The android documentation says that pixels are ARGB not RGB, but it should not matter I think. Most likely the problem is elsewhere.